# Как циклом прочитать значение в массиве через JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Надо циклом вывести значения

```
var sora = "one";
var aros = "two";
var arr = new Array(sora, aros)
```

Answer (score 2):

Обойти все элементы массива:

```
var arr = [ 1, 2, 3 ],
    i, ei;
//Нативный цикл
for( i = 0, ei = arr.length; i < ei; i++ ){
  alert(arr[i]);
}
//Встроенный цикл
arr.forEach( function(el){
  alert(el);
} );
```

Таким способом пользоваться нельзя ( для массива нельзя ):

```
for(var i in a) {
    alert(a[i]);
}
```

т.к. кроме a[0] ... a[n], будет вызвано, как минимум - alert(a['length']); а в реальной задаче - ещё любое кол-во добавленных свойств.

P.S:
Может возникнуть вопрос, почему стоит писать **for( i = 0, ei = arr.length; i < ei; i++ )**, а не привычное(?) **for( i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ )**.
Разъясню:
При каждой итерации массива, будет проходить проверка условия, и во втором случае потребуется обращение к свойству объекта **arr.length**, что в общем случае медленнее чем обращение к локальной переменнной **ei**.
Дело в том, что интерпритатор не кеширует значение arr.length, т.к. в общем случае возможна запись вида: **for(i=0; i < getMax(); i++)**.
Не верующие могут попробовать данный код:

```
m = function(){ alert('iter'); return 4};
for(i=0;i<m();i++){}
```

Comment: про <pre></code>for in</pre></code> солидарен на 100%, к тому-же, пускай и незначительно, но все-же работает это медленее чем for...<br>

Comment: про ei тоже верно подмечено, но это, в абсолютном большинстве случаев, экономия на спичках :)

Comment: На самом деле, из таких мелочей, складывается комок!<br>
Например использование ~~(1.1) вместо Math.floor(1.1) или parseInt(1.1) быстрее в 10+ раз. ( что лично для меня - загадка! )

Comment: Сразу видно что вы не имели дела с С,С++ :)<br>
Вот там загадок... xD

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    alert(arr[i]);
}
```

Лучше объявить массив так

```
var a = ["one", "two"];
```

Тогда проход по значениям такой

```
for(var i in a) {
    alert(a[i]);
}
```

Comment: и чем это лучше?

Comment: а так можно????
for (i = arr; i; i++)

Comment: нет конечно...

Comment: почему нельзя?

Comment: потому что это бред!